# Is there errata available for the Infinite Undiscovery BradyGames guide?

Tags: infinite-undiscovery

Via reviews, it appears that there are issues with the official strategy guide.

I've run into a few minor ones, but just read about a missing side quest (Michelle's Lover in Nolaan) and private event.

Is there errata, official or otherwise, for the official guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used Split Infinity's guide since the 3rd or 4th, based upon what I've gone through, the major thing that I've discovered is that the guide skips over the Kolton experience, before the final boss.

Since you don't go back to Kolton you also don't view the 'Secret of _' events, which means you can't unlock IC level 6. It *appears* you can still unlock these in the end-game, however.

There's minor mistakes in what awards you receive for doing certain things, but these really are relatively minor (in my opinion). (There is one that has a bigger reward than advertised, but it's tied to an achievement, so it's unlikely to cause too much trouble.)

The sidequest-specific FAQ on GameFAQs seems to have been ripped directly from the official guide, and Split Infinity numbers his differently. Michelle's Lover (SI's #15) appears to be missing from the official guide, but the reward isn't unique, and completing all sidequests isn't an achievement.

I've found the [Hints and Tips guide on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/935661-infinite-undiscovery/faqs/56564) to be useful for missable items (despite that I'm not even going to try getting all items).

At this point, I believe I can say the only key point is to travel back to Kolton before heading on to the Underwater Palace. Of course, if you're just in it for the story, you should be fine with the official book. And if you want to get every item for the achievement, you'll obviously want to use a fan-crafted FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon and Ebay are each only returning the original guide printed on September 25, 2008. This would indicate there was never a reprinted version of this guide. The cost that Square-Enix and Brady Games would incur by reprinting corrected strategy guides is too large for them to consider a reprint justifiable, especially for a game with as poor of sales as *Infinite Undiscovery*.

However, [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/935661-infinite-undiscovery/faqs/54136) at gamefaqs.com was published February 27, 2011. It runs through the game start to finish.

Comment: Yeah, Split Infinity makes pretty good guides. I ended up using his shortly after I posted my question, and have added an answer with my experience. Technical books often have online errata, and a long while back I had a couple strategy guides that had them as well. Sometimes you'll even find fan-based sites/guides that list out the issues with the official guides. I hadn't seen anything, which I thought was a little surprising, but given that it's an Xbox 360-exclusive RPG that's not done by Mistwalker ... I suppose it makes sense.